# Product of largest elements in 2 array

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to get the product of largest non equal element from 2 dynamically allocated arrays 
(for example if array 1 is : 7,5,9 and array 2 is: 8,9,1 product should be 9*8= 72).
However the result is never accurate with me, I started debugging but couldn't figure out the problem too

please find my code below

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int size;
    cin >> size;

    int *arr1 = new int[size];

    int *arr2 = new int[size];

    int max1;
    int max2;
    max1 = 0;
    max2 = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << "Please enter the elements for first array" << endl;
        cin >> arr1[i];
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < size; k++)
    {
        cout << "Please enter the elements for second array" << endl;
        cin >> arr2[k];
    }

    for (int l = 0; l < size; l++)
    {
        if(arr1[l]>max1)
        {
            max1 = arr1[l];
        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        if (arr2[j]>max2 && arr2[j]!=max1)
        {
            max2 = arr1[j];
        }
    }

    int product;
    product = max1*max2;

    cout << "product is = " << product << endl;

    delete []arr1;
    delete []arr2;
}
```

Comment: Who said that elements of those arrays are always positive numbers?

Comment: @ThomasSablik The number must not be duplicated, I need to take the maximum from each array but the must not be equal so in second array I take the second largest element

Comment: Ironically, given your order of input, you don't need arrays for this in the first place. Just read the first set of numbers, and determine the max *as you read them*. Once you know an item is-not replacing the current max, you don't need it anymore.  Repeat that for the second set. Then, multiply the two results and you have your answer.

Comment: The problem is that you are looking for the largest element in the first array and the largest  element of the second array that isn't in the first array. That doesn't work in all cases. You could store the two largest elements of both arrays and find the largest possible product

Comment: @WhozCraig the problem statement is to get it from array of integers

Comment: "The number must not be duplicated" you should say all requirements before people look into your solution. Again does it say that numbers are always positive?

Comment: Have you tried using `cout` to display both arrays to make sure your arrays are getting populated as expected? Then might be worthwhile to display the `max1` and `max2` to determine if you're extracting the max

Comment: @Slava I am trying the easy scenario, but if you may tell me how to do it negative integers I will appreciate it much , thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean easy scenario? Do you need to make it work? Easy scenario is to print a random number.

Comment: @YoussefEl-Maraghy I C. I thought the problem was to find the product of the max elements of two series of numbers. There are better uses for arrays than this (a simple sort requirement, for example). Anyway, what I said stands; arrays are pointless to achieve this problem solution. If they're required for your homework, it's by nuance; not necessity.

Comment: @Slava I have mentioned in the requirement "Non equal element" linguistically it gives the same meaning of "non duplicated" .

Comment: Ok non equal are there, missed it. But it does not say that elements are positive

Comment: @YoussefEl-Maraghy, the question is meaningless the way it is worded at the moment. It refers to maximum elements **of the two arrays separately**; it never refers to whether their product has to be maximum/minimum/positive/negative/happy/angry. The task "take the largest non-equal elements from two arrays" is illogical, for the reason I explained in my point 3. I will explain better.

Comment: Question flagged for _Needs details or clarity_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several bugs in your attempt:

1. One is possibly a typo, as in the second `if` the line `max2 = arr1[j];` should be `max2 = arr2[j];`;
2. <s>Another one is conceptual: you are not considering that two negative numbers' product is positive; however, this might simply be a choice of yours;</s> this is not really relevant, in view of point 3; however I would reword it as a question: *what about negative numbers?*
3. Another bug (the main bug, I'd say) is conceptual: if `arr1` and `arr2` have the same maximum entry, then you have somehow to choose from which one you want to give up the maximum to take the second to largest entry. Your code always chooses to take the maximum from `arr1`; so, for instance, if `arr1` is `[1, 2, 3]` and `arr2` is `[0, 1, 3]` you will end up choosing `3` from `arr1` and `1` from `arr2`. But if you had taken the maximum from `arr2`, then you would end up with `2` from `arr1` and `3` from `arr2`: which one is better? Nobody can say, as the question gives no way to make the choice.

In fact, bug 3, with the related example, just reveals that the statement of the problem (the request, if you want) is faulty by itself.

As a side note which can be useful for you to know in general, you can declare and initialize a variable in the same line, as in:

```
int max1 = 0;
```

instead of

```
int max1;
max1 = 0;
```

Comment: simple test case {10,9} and {10,5} produces wrong output.

Comment: @TruthSeeker, the questions is about _**the** product of largest non equal element from 2 dynamically allocated arrays_. Therefore with reference to your example, `10*5` is not right nor wrong, as **the** product of [...] does not necessarily exist, and your example just proves that. However I have listed this conceptual bug in my answer.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis : you can take max 2 elements from both the arrays and check `max(max1[0]*max2[1],max1[1]*max2[0])`

Comment: @TruthSeeker that will give you 10 * 10 which is incorrect.

Comment: @TruthSeeker, could you please take a minute or less to look at my update answer? Lesson for myself: _never answer a buggy question_.

Comment: Your point 2 seems to be incorrect (I was confused for that too) OP is looking for product of 2 largest (non equal) elements, not the largest product.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the arrays and compare the largest elements. If they are same return the largest product of one largest element and one second largest element:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int size;
    cin >> size;

    int *arr1 = new int[size];

    int *arr2 = new int[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << "Please enter the elements for first array" << endl;
        cin >> arr1[i];
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < size; k++)
    {
        cout << "Please enter the elements for second array" << endl;
        cin >> arr2[k];
    }

    std::sort(arr1, arr1 + size);

    std::sort(arr2, arr2 + size);

    cout << "product is = ";
    if (arr1[size-1] != arr2[size-1])
        cout << arr1[size-1] * arr2[size-1] << endl;
    else
        cout << std::max(arr1[size-1] * arr2[size-2], arr1[size-2] * arr2[size-1]) << endl;

    delete []arr1;
    delete []arr2;
}
```

Input:

```
3
7 5 9
8 9 1
```

Output:

```
product is = 72
```

Comment: Fail to produce right o/p for for {9,8,5} and {9,8,6}

Comment: @TruthSeeker The result is 9 * 8 = 72.  9 and 8 are the _largest non equal element from 2 dynamically allocated arrays_. I understand this sentence as the largest two elements, one from first array and the second array that are not equal. 9 and 8 are not equal. I don't understand it as the largest unique elements

Answer (score -1):

Ok you have 2 conceptual issues in your code:

1 you assume that you will get at least one positive number, but requirement does not say it. If all numbers are negative you will get wrong result.

2 Your looking for largest number is wrong, lets say you have 2 arrays: [7,8,9] and [6,7,9] you will give 9 * 7 instead of 8 * 9.

Here is the proper solution:

```
std::vector<int> v1( size ), v2( size );

// make sure that size >= 2 and enter data

std::nth_element( v1.begin(), v1.begin() + 1, v1.end(), std::greater<int>() );
std::nth_element( v2.begin(), v2.begin() + 1, v2.end(), std::greater<int>() );

int product = v1[0] * ( v1[0] == v2[0] ? std::max( v1[1], v2[1] ), v2[0] );
```

Comment: The question never mentions _the maximum product_, so `9*7` vs `8*9` is not relevant. None of them is right or wrong, as the question is bugged, therefore there is **no** proper solution.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis right but 8 and 9 largest elements that are larger than 9 and 7. So I stand for it, but requirements are quite confusing, I agree.

Comment: The sentence "there exist only one way to take the biggest two elements from the two vectors provided the two elements are not equal", whcih is implied by the question wordig, is not confusing; it is a **logical** absurdity.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis where did you get this sentence from?

Comment: The question reads _get the product of largest non equal element from 2 [...] arrays_. **get the** implies that the product exist, hence the two numbers exist. larg-**est** implies that there's a unique way to pick the two elements.